# Xcode Version 6.0 (6A313) - Error creating LLDB target

Tags: ios8, xcode6, lldb

I tried running my project in Xcode Version 6.0 (6A313) and received **Error creating LLDB target at path '/path' - using an empty LLDB target which can cause slow memory reads from remote devices.** But it runs perfectly on xcode 5.1. I think the problem with architecture of iOS 8. Is this is a serious problem i should take care of ? Anyone help me with some suggestions.

Comment: I tried other answers relating this problem on this site. nothing solved my issue.